# MediaPlayer or AVFoundation stop working eventually

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, media-player, avfoundation

I have a strange problem with MediaPlayer or AVFoundation. At some random point in the app, it stops working. With MPMoviePlayerViewController for instance it is automatically dismissed without playing the movie; with `[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:movieURL options:nil];`
it returns nil. 
The thing is that when I close the app, also from the OS background, and restart it, it will start working again.
My question is if why does it happen, or if it is a way of reset something so it could start working again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing any code, but, if `[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:movieURL options:nil];` is returning nil, then my guess would be that movieURL is no longer valid.

How are you creating movieURL? How are you releasing it?

My suggestion is to set a breakpoint where you call `[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:movieURL options:nil];` and check the value for movieURL. I am willing to be that it will be nil when the movie fails to load.

Comment: I see I didn't accept this one, I fixed long time ago but your answer is helpful for others. I did not release the object, so they were leaking in memory as hell. Thanks.